# Can a Partner Community have multiple templates?

Tags: partner-communities, page-template

Hi I have a Partner Community with 20 users.  Out of the 20users I am using 3 different roles and one profile.  I want each role to see a different template.  How would I go about doing this? Is this possible?

For ex.  User with role A will see a flower template, User with role B will see a Car template, etc.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by template here?

Comment: Each Role I would like to display a specific logo.  I believe Page variations is the solution.

Comment: How is this on hold?  glls gave the perfect solution to my answer.  I even gave an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using [Page variations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_manage_pages_overview.htm&type=5) and [Audience Targeting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_visibilty_overview.htm&type=5)
Audience targeting however, supporte only the following:

> - Profile
> - Location
> - Domain
> - User Object
> - Record Type
> - Permission

if you absolutely require to do so using role(s), then, you can change/modify the layout by using [Custom Page layouts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_layout.htm&r=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.ca%2F&type=5) or [Content Layouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_layouts.htm)

Comment: Thanks I am doing the Page variations of trailhead.